# How to use a Phoenix controller variable in JavaScript?

Tags: reactjs, elixir, phoenix-framework

How do I use a variable from Phoenix controller in my JavaScript?

I'm using React for front-end.

I can't use `<%= ... %>` in JavaScript.

```
defmodule Familytree.PageController do
  use Familytree.Web, :controller

  alias Familytree.Users
  alias Familytree.Tags
  alias Familytree.UserTag

  plug Familytree.Plugs.Auth
  plug :scrub_params, "users" when action in [:create, :update]
  plug :scrub_params, "tags" when action in [:add_tag,:delete_tag]

  def index(conn, _params) do
    users = Repo.all(Users)
    tags = Repo.all(Tags)
    render(conn, "index.html", users: users, tags: tags, current_user: get_session(conn, :current_user))
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you want to load the data only once on the initial page load?

Comment: yes. I need that object because I'm doing search bar so I need all the names from that object

Answer (score 2):

You could try rendering the value in view to build HTML attribute and then obtain this with your JavaScript, which is rather common prctice.

Something like this could do:

*my_view.eex*

```
<div data-name="<%= @some_name_from_controller %>" id="component">
</div>
```

*script.js*

```
var name = $("#component").data("name");
```

You can find more about `data` [here](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Hope that helps!

Comment: yeah that doesn't work for me. maybe I'm doing something wrong I don't know.  when I put this line 
<div data-name="<%= @users %>" id="ake"></div>
I get argument error

Comment: @ake What kind of error are you receiving? Could you provide more information and paste more code (eg. from your controller)?

Comment: when I write this line: <div id="ake" data-name="<%= 'at'user %>"></div>
I get this error
assign @user not available in eex template.
In my controller I have:   alias Familytree.Users and this is where I have all the information that I need to use in my javascript

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't provide all information I need to help you. Would you be able to edit your question and provide richer snippets of your code? This could help significantly.

Comment: @ake, quickly glancing through your files it seems you set `users` in your controller, but in your view, you're trying to access `user`, thus, the reason you see `error assign @user not available in eex template`

Comment: yeah that was when I tried something else. I tried users as well but that's not working either. when I type users that I have some other error, I can't remember exactly but it says something that the lists uses only integer... You know that error?
p.s. can you recommend some good tutorial or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PhoenixGon](https://github.com/khusnetdinov/phoenix_gon) it bring all phoenix variables to window scope and you can use all this variables, and it also generate js methods for getting this vars:

```
def index(conn, _params) do
  put_gon(conn, [users: Repo.all(Users), tags: Repo.all(Tags)])
  render(conn, "index.html", current_user: get_session(conn, :current_user))
end
```

and use it from browser console or in javascript module:

```
window.Gon.getAsset('users')
// => [user, user1 ...]
```

It also helps keep js vars and html.eex vars in different parts and keeps it clear.